# Why would std::unordered_map::emplace() fail?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

I have a `std::unordered_map` that I `emplace()` an object to via:

```
my_map.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
               std::forward_as_tuple(key),
               std::forward_as_tuple(value1, value2));
```

This fails at some point during runtime with a `false` in the second position of the returned tuple. Is there a way to get more information about what's going on? `top` doesn't show any trouble with memory.

Comment: True men don't read manuals, but programmers sometimes should: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I read http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace multiple times. The "Return value" section wasn't as clear to me as Angew's answer.

Comment: Fair point, the documentation for `emplace` should be improved, it is missing a key sentence from the documentation of `insert`: the conditions under which it can fail to insert *without throwing* and exception.

Comment: Q: I tried to improve the documentation in cppreference a bit, but I am not sure how much clearer it is now. Is it clearer?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Which document did you change? I don't see any recent revision history for either unordered_map or emplace.

Comment: The wiki is a bit of a mess to edit, as most of the information is pulled from templates. I updated the template that generates the description of `emplace` for associative containers, which includes `std::unordered_map`. The change is in the first paragraph of the rendered documentation for `emplace`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A `false` in `.second` means "equivalent element already present." In such case, the iterator in `.first` points to that equivalent element.

So what's happening is that you already have `key` in the map, and you can use `.first` on the return value to access it.